# Is $n!a$, $a$ irrational, equidistributed mod 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been trying without success to prove a weaker result, that the fractional part of $n!a$, where $a$ is irrational, does not tend to $1/2$ as $n$ tends to infinity. My objective was to show that for each real $x$ $(n-1)!\cos(n!x)$ (the derivative of $n^{-1}\sin(n!x)$) does not converge as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I think this will be equidistributed for (Lebesgue) almost every $a$, but, for each $u\in[0,1)$ there will be an uncountable dense (in fact, comeagre) set of values for $a$ for which $n!a$ tends to $u$ mod 1.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of the title is NO, since 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n! e \mod 1) =0.$$
It is because $|e-\sum_{k=0}^n 1/k!| \leq \frac{e}{n.n!}$ (use Taylor formula).

Answer (score 0):

I shall try to enlighten your main objective

Take any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed say $ x = a$. So you shall get your sequence as $(n-1)!\cos{(n!a)}$. We know $\cos{(n!a)}$ is bounded for any $n$ and $a$. Now consider the limit,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (n-1)!\cos{(n!a)} = \infty or -\infty$$.

This is true for arbitrary $x = a \in \mathbb{R}$. So for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, derivative of $\frac{\sin{n!x}}{n}$, does not converge pointwise, and so not uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why positive infinite - surely $cos(n!a)$ is equally likely to be negative as well as positive?

Comment: Yes, it may be negative but never exist finitely.

Comment: Yep, indeed - I was being pedantic

Comment: "This is true for arbitrary x=a"... Why?

Comment: Take any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed (remember we are not considering limit on $x$), and see $\cos{(n!a)}$, is bounded whenever $n$ is, as $|\cos{\theta}| \leq 1 \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$. So your choice on $a$ will never affect the limit on $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So the result is true for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: @user10676 Thanks for the answer to the title question! As for the the divergence of $(n-1)!\cos(n!x)$ for each real $x$, it does not suffice to note that $\cos(n!x)$ is bounded---for example $1\n!$ is bounded but $(n-1)!\frac{1}{n!}$ converges. Any help on that?

Comment: @mariella Nice example. But two cases are different. Boundedness of $\cos{(n!x)}$ does not depend on $n$, and so $(n-1)!\cos{(n!x)}$ depends on $(n-1)!$ only. Whereas in $\{(n-1)!\frac{1}{n!}\}$, the ultimate value is $\frac{1}{n}$, so convergent.

Comment: Why does there not exist a real $x$ for which $\cos(n!x)$ goes to zero fast enough (i.e., the fractional part of $n!x$ goes to $\frac{1}{2}$ fast enough) so that $(n-1)!\cos(n!x)$ might converge?

Comment: Reason is that boundedness of $\cos{(n!x)}$ depends neither on $n$ nor $x$. Please come to the point. The sequence of functions $(n-1)!\cos{(n!x)}$ does not converge pointwise (check it keeping $x$ fixed) so can not converge anyhow.